# Horizontal scrollbar disappeared

Tags: scrollbar, overflow

My horizontal scroll bar doesn't appear when I decrease the window size of my browser. It is because I have overflow:hidden on two of my containers... however I need this as I am using floating elements and the background images don't show unless I use overflow:hidden. Is there a work-around to use achieve both things? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://actorscms.co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is a good idea to make the horizontal scroll work. You should probably check some responsivness and media queries and make your website adjusts to viewport width.

Comment: Simply it is not a good approach. 
But you can also try some clearfix like in bootstrap. Add this class to #wrapper and #wrapper2
.clearfix:after, .clearfix:before { display:table; content: " " }

If you have made some jsfiddle it would be easier.

Comment: I would prefer not to create a fluid layout that adjusts to viewport width for this website, so is there any other option or is it best to leave it as it is? Thanks a lot for replying and helping me

Comment: Have you tried the clearfix method? It should do what you need :) It is not too good to leave it as it is... Some users wont see some content.

Comment: I am going to try that now, but I just read that these days floating elements are discouraged as there are better alternatives. Would it be worth finding a different method to layout my page without the use of float? THANKS

Comment: ...I have implemented the clear fix but I cannot see any change? http://actorscms.co.uk

Comment: Floating is a good method. Better than table layout, that is sure! 
Delete overflow: hidden from wrappers.

Comment: THANKS! That works brilliantly! Only problem is, is when you decrease the browser size now, and scroll horizontally, the background doesn't cover the scrolled section. Is there anything I can do to resolve this? It's live http://actorscms.co.uk

Comment: For repeating background in wrapper2 you can simply add background also to content2, also add clearfix to content2. 
Actually, add clearfix to every parent div that has some floating inside.

But as you can see, without media queries and responsivness, if you reduce the window width to less than 960px menu starts disapearing.

Also remember to use firebug (in firefox) or other developer console (F12 or CTRL+SHIFT+i to open)

Comment: Ok! I think I have fixed all the problems, if you have a moment I don't suppose you could run your eyes over it just to see if anything jumps out at you as a problem! I really appreciate your help. Thank you. http://actorscms.co.uk

Comment: I think all is fine. No problem!